# ASP.MVC IUserRoleStore<> isn't called at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've implemented a custom user store for my web application. So far everything works fine.
Now I wanted to extend the store class, to support roles. I implemented the following interfaces:

```
IUserStore<UserViewModel>, IUserLockoutStore<UserViewModel, string>, IUserPasswordStore<UserViewModel, string>, IUserTwoFactorStore<UserViewModel, string>, IUserRoleStore<UserViewModel, string>, IRoleStore<RoleModel, string>
```

And registered the services with the Owin AppBuilder as follows:

```
var ctx = UnityMvcActivator.Context.Container;
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ctx.Resolve<WebUserManager>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ctx.Resolve<RoleManager>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ctx.Resolve<WebApplicationUserStore>());
```

If I go back to my controller and call `User.IsInRole(Constants.Roles.COMPANY_OWNER)` the store will not be called to get the roles of the user. I guess there is some kind of missing link but I can't find it.
I also implemented a `UserManager<UserViewModel, string>` with the `SupportsUserRole` property explicitly set to true, which makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.IsInRole` does not check your database, only checks the current user cookie. It will get you roles that are stored in the cookie, but these might be different from what you'll have from in the database. The difference might crop up if user roles changed since the last time cookie being refreshed.

If you need to check roles in the database use `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151686(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.IsInRoleAsync(%601,System.String)))

Comment: The solution works fine for User.IsInRole, but the AuthorizeAttibute will not work with. It will filter all requests and redirect to the login page.